# Picture Upload MVC / Javascript / ASP.NET C#

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm building a HTML5 mobile application with bootsrap.
At this moment I'm having some problems with the upload feature.

This is my HTML form:

```
<form id="login-form">
    <input   type="file" id="files" accept="image/*;capture=camera" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">
    <button type="submit" onclick="ButtonSumbit()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And here is my submit button code:

```
function ButtonSumbit()
{
    var cURL = document.URL;

    var postdata = $('#login-form').serialize();
    var file = document.getElementById('files').files[0];
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("files", file);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "/TakePicture/TakePictureDB", false);

    xhr.send(fd);

    var jsonObj = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

    if (jsonObj.PictureWasSaved == true) {
        console.log("Image Uploaded!");
        alert("OK");
    }
    else {
        console.log("Image was not Uploaded!");
    }
};
```

My asp.net code is here:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult TakePictureDB(FormCollection data)
    {
        try
        {
            //Check Permission
            if (EloGlobal.UserHasPermissionTo("CODE", EloGlobal.PermissionType.Read) == false)
            {
                throw new Exception(nG.StringsResources.Resources.CurrentUserHasNoPermissions);
            }

            if (Request.Files["files"] != null)
            {
                using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(Request.Files["files"].InputStream))
                {
                    var Imagefile = binaryReader.ReadBytes(Request.Files["files"].ContentLength);//your image
                }

                return Json(new { PictureWasSaved = true },
                JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            else
            {
                return Json(new { PictureWasSaved = false },
                JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            LogException(ex, "Start", "Home");
            Session["error"] = ex;
        }
        //Error
        return Json(new { PictureWasSaved = false },
                        JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

The code is running ok.
The problem is when I click in the submit button my page redirect me to my log in page.
I think the problem is aimed to url change, because after the submit button click, my url change to:
localhost:62636/? and during navigation in my application the url didn't change, is always the same* localhost:62636/

Can anyone give me some help? thank you

Comment: It seems to me like you're submitting the form to an empty action before you're actually even doing anything. Setting a value in the "onclick" attribute does not prevent the default action of a click by itself. You'll need to pass the click event through and then call preventDefault() on it to ensure that you're not trying to submit this form in the classic HTML sense. What I would do is bind to the submit event on the form, see what I did in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/651y41qd/)

Also, you spelled Submit wrong ;)

Comment: I change the button to:
<button type="submit" onclick="ButtonSubmit();return false;">Submit</button>

as you told and it works! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `return false;` after the call of your `ButtonSubmit` function to remove the default page submit behaviour of a `submit` button.

```
<button type="submit" onclick="ButtonSumbit();return false;">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Yep, or change the input type to button.